# Set White Balance, ISO, Aperture & Shutter Speed with Night Mode and Exposure using CameraX and Camera2

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-camera2, android-camerax

I'm trying to set the camera preview White Balance, ISO, Aperture & Shutter Speed with Night Mode and Exposure settings for my app. I have set night mode and exposure setting using CameraX, and figured out settings option for rest of the settings using Camera 2. How can I use CameraX and Camera2 at the same time for camera preview?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Camera2Interop to add custom Custom capture request in your use cases.

Refer this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60583685/11861734